# React router dom 6.14 and defer not awaiting the data

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I using the react router dom 6.14 and try using the defere , suspense and await as in thier doc , and no matter what im doing its seems like the fallback never rendered.

here me code.

```
//route.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <App />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/products/:category",
          element: <ProductsMain />,
          loader: (req) => getItems(req),
        },
        {
          path: "/settings",
          element: <SettingsComponent />,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "test",
      element: <TestComonenet />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    },
  ]);
```

```
//loader 

export async function getItems(request: any, primaryStore: StoreEn, otherStores: StoreEn[]) {
  // const body = getBodyFromStorage();
 
  try {
    const url = `${urlBE}/products/${request.params.category}`;
    const data = serverAPI(url, body, "success"); // ===> its a promise
return defer(data:
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

/// shortcut on the server api:

```
const serverAPI = async (url: productsEP, body: any, description?: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      const { message } = await response.json();
      throw new Error(message);
    }
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    return { data: jsonData, error: null, description: description };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

now for the ProductsMain component:

```
const ProductsMain = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const data: any = useLoaderData();


  return (
<Suspense fallback={<p>Loader...</p>}
    <Await resolve={data} >
      {(data) => (
            <>
              <Products data={data}/>
              
            </>
          )}
    <Await />
</Suspense>
  );
};
```

somehow its seems the loader never happens . and also the data is just a promise and i cant render it (although i get the data with status code 200)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem may the code below will help you. And the defer should work by that by which method you did. So change some of the followings as below, may this works.

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loader...</p>}
        <Await resolve={data} >
          {(data) => (
                <>
                  <Products data={data}/>
                  
                </>
              )}
        </div>
        <Await />
    
    </React.Suspense>
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Basically this solves nothing. It is absolutely the same code from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loader to the following..

```js
//loader 

export type GetItemsType = {
  dataPromise: Promise<any>
}

export function getItems(request: any) 
{
  const body = getBodyFromStorage();
  const url = `${urlBE}/products/${request.params.category}`;
  const deferredObj: GetItemsType = { dataPromise: serverAPI(url, body, "success") };
  return defer(deferredObj);
}
```

Notice the ommition of the `try-catch` statement as the error should be caught and handled in an `Await` component. Also removed the `async` modifier because no promise is awaited in the loader.
The argument of `defer()` should be an object and its properties are accessed like this..

```js
import { GetItemsType } from 'PATH-TO-(GetItemsType)'
const ProductsMain = () =>
{
  // const [products, setProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const data = useLoaderData() as GetItemsType;

  <Suspense fallback={<p>Loader...</p>}
    <Await resolve={data.dataPromise} errorElement={<AsyncErrorHandler />} >
      {
        (data: any) => (<Products data={data}/>)
      }
    <Await />
  </Suspense>
}
```

Notice the `errorElement` has the value `<AsyncErrorHandler />` which is, as the name suggests, the component that handles the deferred error, and it's done as follows..

```js
const AsyncErrorHandler = () =>
{
  const error = useAsyncError();
  return <div>{error.message}</div>;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that my knowledge in `react-router-dom` is somewhat limited and my answer is based off of what I know, so hope it helps.